# Using Grunt with Django: Best Workflow

Tags: javascript, django, gruntjs

I have inherited a `Django` site from another person and I'm trying to use `Grunt.js` alongside it. My app directory structure looks like:

```
app_name
 |__ pages
 |__ settings
 |__ static
     |__ config.rb
     |__ css
     |__ Gruntfile.js
     |__ img
     |__ js
     |__ node_modules
     |__ package.json
     |__ sass
 |__ templates
 |__ etc
```

Should I be using `Grunt` within the `static` directory? - i.e. Is it best practice to use `Grunt` in the root of the folder (in this case alongside `app_name`)?

When I upload my `css/scripts` to production, I don't want the `Gruntfile.js` to be visible.

Comment: I put the grunt file outside the django project, directly above it. I need grunt accessible from any subdirectory, whereas in your setup I'd have to navigate to the static folder to fire up grunt.

Also depends on what exactly you're using it for; is its scope specifically local to the static files? I use it for much more, including running multiple dev servers. Therefore it's appropriate at the project root.

Comment: I'm using it for Sass/js concatenation/js minification etc, all front-end workflow based. So you're suggesting that the Gruntfile/package.json be at the same level as `app_name` ?

Comment: Have a look at [django cookiecutter](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django). IMHO it has a good layout.

Answer (score 2):

You can symlink Gruntfile and node_modules from upper folders to current, this way grunt build will works well and you will not store cfg file in static folder. Other way is to exclude it with your packaging system like deb or rpm.